# Why xdebug not stop on breakpoint?

Tags: php, wordpress, netbeans, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a problem by xdebug in NetBeans and also PhpStorm! 
After running the project in each IDE, in chrome it display this :

[image]

but it doesn't stop on any breakpoints!

[image]

However in NetBeans when I check Stop on first line of file, it stops on first line and I can debug that file, but again I have problem with break points too.

My php.ini Xdebug :

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\zend_ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You can use the "https://xdebug.org/wizard.php" to get proper configuration as per you php version, and check the connection configuration between netbeans and xdebug.

Comment: @AshishRanade Thank you AshishRanade. I did it and I set instructions. but not works yet!

Comment: have you defined the landing path for dubugger

Comment: @NN what's your mean of landing path?

Comment: Please provide screenshot of actual whole **PhpStorm** window when you are trying to debug. So far it looks like you are doing JavaScript debug and not PHP (as such browser bar message is not shown for PHP -- only for JavaScript). Have a look: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Provide debugger the index.php for landing up on browser. Once browser is opened your debugger will start working